# Correct CMake configuration for LibMongoCxx

Tags: c++, mongodb, cmake, mongo-cxx-driver

I am working on a project using the MongoDB C++ library 3.5.0 and I am having trouble figuring out how to include mongocxx correctly using CMake.

Right now mongocxx is included in CMake like this:

```
find_package(libmongocxx REQUIRED)
include_directories(${LIBMONGOCXX_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${LIBMONGOCXX_LIBRARIES})
```

Which works fine for building my minimal example:

```
// main.cpp:
#include <mongocxx/instance.hpp>

int main()
{
    mongocxx::instance instance{};
}
```

However when running CMake I get the following warning:

```
CMake Warning at /usr/lib64/cmake/libmongocxx-3.5.0/libmongocxx-config.cmake:15 (message):
  This CMake target is deprecated.  Use 'mongo::mongocxx_shared' instead.
  Consult the example projects for further details.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:16 (find_package)
```

I would like to get rid of this for one to declutter my CMake output and also because the current way is depreceated.

When I use the advice from the warning `find_package(mongo::mongocxx_shared REQUIRED)` or `find_package(mongocxx_shared REQUIRED)` I get an error stating `Could not find a package configuration file provided by "mongocxx_shared"`. Looking at what's available I see:

```
[georg@archlinux build]$ locate mongo | grep cxx | grep .cmake
/usr/include/mongocxx/v_noabi/mongocxx/cmake
/usr/lib/cmake/libmongocxx-3.5.0
/usr/lib/cmake/mongocxx-3.5.0
/usr/lib/cmake/libmongocxx-3.5.0/libmongocxx-config-version.cmake
/usr/lib/cmake/libmongocxx-3.5.0/libmongocxx-config.cmake
/usr/lib/cmake/mongocxx-3.5.0/mongocxx-config-version.cmake
/usr/lib/cmake/mongocxx-3.5.0/mongocxx-config.cmake
/usr/lib/cmake/mongocxx-3.5.0/mongocxx_targets-release.cmake
/usr/lib/cmake/mongocxx-3.5.0/mongocxx_targets.cmake
```

`mongocxx-config.cmake` exists and therefore I tried `find_package(mongocxx REQUIRED)`which makes CMake no longer complains however now the variables `${LIBMONGOCXX_INCLUDE_DIRS}` and `${LIBMONGOCXX_LIBRARIES}` stay empty and the compiler cant find the includes as a consequence.

What is the correct way to include this library without running into the depreceated warning?

As a reference here is the complete CMake file I am using at the moment:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

project(
    test
    VERSION 0.1.0
)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main.cpp
)

find_package(libmongocxx REQUIRED)
find_package(mongocxx REQUIRED)

include_directories(${LIBMONGOCXX_INCLUDE_DIRS})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${LIBMONGOCXX_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: I believe warning means use `mongo::mongocxx_shared` instead of `${LIBMONGOCXX_LIBRARIES}`

Comment: @drescherjm thanks, can you give me an idea of the syntax? This gives me `Invalid character (':') in a variable name: 'mongo'`.

Comment: `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} mongo::mongocxx_shared)` instead of `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${LIBMONGOCXX_LIBRARIES})`

Comment: That's not it. I can isolate the warning to whether I am using `find_package(libmongocxx REQUIRED)` or `find_package(mongocxx REQUIRED)` even if the other lines `include_directories` and `target_link_libraries` are commented out.

Comment: You may have to read line 15 of `/usr/lib64/cmake/libmongocxx-3.5.0/libmongocxx-config.cmake` to see more info.

Comment: The warning seems to be from the file [libmongocxx-config.cmake.in](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/master/src/mongocxx/cmake/libmongocxx-config.cmake.in), which is used (after configuration) when call `find_package` with `libmongocxx` as the name of the package. But the file [mongocxx-config.cmake.in](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/master/src/mongocxx/cmake/mongocxx-config.cmake.in) lacks for this warning message. Have you tried to search the package `mongocxx` instead? As in your second `find_package` call.